# How to get the string which are match with column value in full text search SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, full-text-search

just like below `query`, It's show `score`. I want the same with string or word which are match with

```sql
SELECT Opinion, MATCH(Opinion) AGAINST('nice language' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score 
FROM opinions 
WHERE MATCH(Opinion) AGAINST ('nice language' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Outputs:

```
+---------------------------------------+-------+
| Opinion                               | Score |
+---------------------------------------+-------+
| PHP is a very nice language           |     2 |
| Spain is a nice country to visit      |     1 |
| Perl is not as nice a language as PHP |     2 |
+---------------------------------------+-------+
```

But want below output:

```
+---------------------------------------+--------------+
| Opinion                               | String       |
+---------------------------------------+--------------+
| PHP is a very nice language           | nice language|
| Spain is a nice country to visit      | nice         |
| Perl is not as nice a language as PHP | nice language|
+---------------------------------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Edit done please check.

Comment: Any suggestion guys ?

Comment: @DurgeshPandey search string is static or dynamic?

Comment: @Viki888 search string is static .

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a result that looks like below,

[image]

then make use of the below query

```
select Opinion, 
      case 
        when Opinion like '%nice language%' or (Opinion like '% nice %' and Opinion like '% language %') then 'nice language' 
        when Opinion like '% nice %' then 'nice' 
        when Opinion like '% language %' then 'language' 
      end string  
from table1
where 
    Opinion like '%nice language%' 
      OR (Opinion like '% nice %' and Opinion like '% language %') 
      OR Opinion like '% nice %' 
      OR Opinion like '% language %'
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: 1:- is it not possible in fulltext search ?

Comment: and search string is dynamic then ?

Comment: @DurgeshPandey if it is dynamic, then you have to split the strings and substitute in the query accordingly.

Comment: what about full text search ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `full text search`?

Comment: MySQL full-text search, its features that I am using in my query.
please check my query in question.

Comment: @DurgeshPandey If you need a full text search then you need to have a `MATCH()` in your query.